# How do I graph the region of absolute stability for the block mode in a continuous linear multistep method?

Tags: numerical-methods

[solving the block mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvkta.png)
I am trying to find the region of stability for the block mode given in the image

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please use JAX syntax when typing equations. Parts of your equations are not readable even under extreme magnification. A tutorial can be found here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please provide a bit of context and define all variables explicitly. In particular, is $yp$ equal to the the derivative of $y$?